# URL image path showing 404 error

Tags: image, jsp, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

Im trying to display a Image in an img tag with below code but its showing 404 file not found error at browser console.

**Jsp Page:**

```
<img id="img" src="logo.jsp?path=${schoolModel.user_name}" style="width:105px; height:120px;"/>
```

**logo.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="com.slv.CommonUtils.WebSLCMConstants"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedOutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%
File f=null;
try {
    System.out.println("Inside");
    String path=request.getParameter("path");       
        if(path.equals("")){
            f=new File(WebSLCMConstants.img_retrieve_path+"WebSLCM/no_image.jpg");
        } else {
            f=new File(WebSLCMConstants.img_retrieve_path+path);
        }
        String str=f.toString();
        response.setContentType("image/jpg");
        ServletOutputStream sos;
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(str);
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        sos = response.getOutputStream();
        BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(sos);

        int ch =0;
        while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)
        {
            bout.write(ch);
        }
        bin.close();
        fin.close();
        bout.close();
        if (true) return;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

**Showing 404 file not found error at GUI Browser console as below:**

[image: dasd[![]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgbMQ.png)

Comment: What is the value of `WebSLCMConstants.img_retrieve_path`?

Comment: i print sop's in logo.jsp, its not printing,,,   its giving error in src="logo.jsp?paths=${schoolModel.user_name}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSP Page:**

```
<img id="img" src="image.do?path=yourPath" style="width:105px; height:120px;"/>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getImage(String path, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            } else {
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
                ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

                IOUtils.copy(fin, out);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(fin);

                response.flushBuffer();
                return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```